# Django 1.9 Upgrade "Not Supported" issue

Tags: python, python-requests, pyodbc, django-1.9, django-pyodbc-azure

I've been using Django 1.8.7 in my project, after the yesterday's release I have upgraded to 1.9 (I am using VS PVTS and have deleted Django 1.8.7 from my Virtual Environment and installed the packages from the requirements.txt again).

However, whenever I try to build & run my project it gives me an error in the **manage.py** in line:

```
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

saying:

> Django 1.9.0 is not supported.

I am using **Django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure, requests** modules.

What might be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: It honestly could be anything, I would imagine it is caused by one of your installed apps but it would be hard to tell from what you've provided here

Comment: Is there anything that I can provide to you also? Because I have a new installation of django that contains only 1 additional simple app. That's why I don't think there is a complex situation with my issue. Everything is working fine with 1.8.7.

Comment: Well the full error would be a start but what third party modules are you using? It is probably one of those that isn't prepared for django 1.9

Comment: I am using Django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure, requests modules as additions. I am a newbie in both python and vs-pvts environment can you direct me to a path so that I can provide full error logs to you?

Comment: Just edit your question to include the full trace/error. I'd imagine its "django-pyodbc-azure" that is the issue, I say this as its the only one with "django" in its title

Comment: I have updated the question so that it also contain the modules and you're right with the django-pyodbc-azure module because I have removed that module from the project and switched back to SQLite and everything started working again. I guess I should be waiting for the module to be updated for the django 1.9  update. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) github page,

> Dependencies
>
> - Django 1.8.7
> - pyodbc 3.0 or newer

Given that the pyodbc dependency states "or newer" it would appear you'll have to wait until this supports django 1.9 also

---

Update

pyodbc azure has now been updated to support django 1.9

Comment: Thank you @sayse appreciated.

Comment: @Phyticist - No worries, enjoy!

Comment: Django 1.9 came out yesterday; django-pyodbc-azure normally follows a few days later. If you want to test against v1.9, you can modify django-pyodbc-azure in your virtualenv. Here's the line: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/blob/azure-1.8/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py#L11

Comment: Thanks flipper, I don't know anything about pyodbc-azure, @Phyticist - This may interest you too

Comment: Thank you for the info @FlipperPA and thank you for letting me know Sayse

Comment: Additional Info: Related modules are updated according to the Django 1.9 release, so they are available right now.